# Stored procedure is slow in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am calling a stored procedure (that returns data) from Entity Framework using the query below

```
from sp in db.GetSale(bID, SID,m,y).Where(x => x.isActive == true)
select sp
```

If I run this procedure directly, it takes only 2 seconds, but when I call this stored procedure through EF, it is taking 10 to 15 seconds.

Any guidance to improve the situation? I have seen other post here on SO but have no success

Edit

Here is sqlplan for my procedure
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=87DCBD5D3E9AAA57!374

Comment: how many rows does it return?

Comment: there are two major table involved one has 33K and other has 48K rows. In the result I have 134 employees' Sale which comes after grouping. I have added indexes to the foreign key column also

Comment: If i execute procedure directly it is taking 3 sec. but as I call it from entity framework it stated taking long time

Comment: Run SqlProfiler to see what is actually executing against the database. You may find for example that the final filter is evaluating the prior query than filtering in code. With lots of records, this would result in your large delay.

Comment: so just 134 rows coming back from the SP? ok... does the SP/schema make use of anything like persisted-calculated-indexed columns, or anything exotic like that? (basically, I'm wondering if this is a problem in the `SET` options; incompatible combinations can cause persisted-calculated-indexed columns to be ignored, doing to calculation per row as a table scan instead)

Comment: @flem since SPs (unlike UDFs) are not directly composable, we would *expect* the final `isActive == true` to happen in-memory at the caller; that won't necessarily matter if the original unfiltered version takes 2 seconds and returns just 134 rows

Comment: I attached the plan. @gravell exactly I tried to remove where claus just for testing. it doesn't have effect

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect parameter sniffing.

Try applying anti-parameter sniffing code in your procedure. (Assign parameters to local variables before using them).

http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Comment: Or as the OP is using 2008 they can use `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` which is less verbose and slightly more robust (variables can still be sniffed if the statement is subject to a recompile)

Comment: That is great. Solved the issue

Comment: Not sure why, stored procedure's parameter sniffing seems to occurs BECAUSE of Entity framework, but the solution itself works... Definitely 5 times faster with EF when the sniffing is resolve. Still can't explain why there were this huge of a time difference between SQL and EF when sniffing occurs.

Answer (score 2):

bear in mind that your `.Where(x => x.isActive == true)` filter is not applied to the procedure itself. When you are dealing with tables, the filter is passed to the where clause and executed on the DB. On your case, the proc is going to be executed (without the active clause), the the full result set will be returned to the applications and after that the `where` will be applied.

I know you said the proc is faster, but are you sure you are not somehow passing the isActive=true as a parameter to it?

I see you already have parameters on this proc, so maybe if you add status as another parameter and apply it at query level, it will improve your performance.